# react native event response is incorrect

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native event response is incorrect when component stacks.

When i click on red rectangle area, output is 'Th', but i expect is 'Mo'.

I try dynamic calc week by nativeEvent.pageX in onPress event, it's ok.

Is there any other way?

[demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-silence-h6etni)

[image]

real app show:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because of width of your holiday event view.

Just remove `left` from your `holiday` style and it should look good.

[image]

Comment: In fact, i must display across the day.